# how to show an empty gid view?

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid view . how can I see the column title in my page when it doesn't have any data?
I try this:

```
<Empty Data Template>
      no data.
</Empty Data Template>
```

but this isn't what I want. I want to show the column of my grid view even there is no data in it. help me please!

Comment: Do you have an headertemplate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

1) Add `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"` to your GridView

```
<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" runat="server" />
```

2) Your GridView must be bound to data source (at least, an empty collection) for the empty template to show

```
   GridView1.DataSource = [Some DataSource Here];
   GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: " Add ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" to your Grid View" !!  how to do it?

Comment: `<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" runat="server" />`

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting c# 4.0+ you can use `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty` property, otherwise, you'll need to add some custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find what you need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx

I tried and it works!

```
  <asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
    datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
    autogeneratecolumns="true"
    runat="server">

    <emptydatarowstyle backcolor="LightBlue"
      forecolor="Red"/>

    <emptydatatemplate>

      <asp:image id="NoDataImage"
        imageurl="~/images/Image.jpg"
        alternatetext="No Image" 
        runat="server"/>

        No Data Found.  

    </emptydatatemplate> 

  </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: I did this way before, but it's not what I want . I'm going to show header of my columns in grid view.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to do it:

1-By simulate the Input Fields inside

First Cell
                
                
                    Second Cell
                
                
                    Third Cell
                
            
        
        
2-Is to create Empty DataSet and Bind it to the GirdView.

If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            grd_codes.DataSource = ds
            grd_codes.DataMember = ds.Tables(0).TableName

```
        grd_codes.DataBind()

    Else
        Try
            If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then

                ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).NewRow())
                grd_codes.DataSource = ds
                grd_codes.DataBind()
                Dim columnCount As Integer = grd_codes.Rows(0).Cells.Count
                grd_codes.Rows(0).Cells.Clear()
                grd_codes.Rows(0).Cells.Add(New TableCell)
                grd_codes.Rows(0).Cells(0).ColumnSpan = columnCount
                grd_codes.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text = "No Records Found."

            End If
```

I prefer the first way because Binding empty DataSet has some problems.